# Groovy printing Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>> data

Tags: java, groovy

I have `Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>> invoices` as below

```
invLineItems = [INV-Error_Test1:[[LINE:1, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:22], [LINE:2, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:24]], 
            INV-Error_Test2:[[LINE:3, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:26], [LINE:4, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:28,]]]
```

I am trying to print it as below

```
println " INV-Error_Test2 Details "
invLineItems.get('INV-Error_Test2').each{ 
    it.each{
print "LINE = "+ it['LINE'] 
    }
 }
```

And am getting below error `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: LINE for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry`

Could someone help me with printing this data?

NOTE: I actually have a total of 24 headers but to make the question simple i just posted 4 headers(`Line, Invoice_Date,Invoice-Number,Invoice_Total`) and am trying to print only few headers out of 24

UPDATE: Am trying to update the `Map<String,List<Map<String,String>>> invoices` with the invoiceErrors as below

```
InvoiceError // is an entity with below attributes
{ String errorMessage,
  String invoiceNumber    
}
ErrorMessage                                          invoiceNumber   
-------------                                       -------------------     
File Error : The file is in an unsupported format   INV-Error_Test1
Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported             INV-Error_Test1
Line : 2 MATH ERROR                                 INV-Error_Test1
Line : 3 MATH ERROR                                 INV-Error_Test2
Line : 3 Invoice does not foot Reported             INV-Error_Test2
```

Am trying to achieve below map 
    If the error message doesnt have a line number it need to be appended at the top level as `invLineItems.put('error',['INV-Error_Test1' :`File Error : The file is in an unsupported format`])`
   Otherwise errormessage should be appended to the  matching INVOICE and linenumber as below

```
invLineItems = [INV-Error_Test1:[[LINE:1, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:22, error : `Line : 1 Invoice does not foot Reported`], 
                                [LINE:2, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test1, INVOICE_TOTAL:24, error : `Line : 2 MATH ERROR`],
                INV-Error_Test2:[[LINE:3, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:26, , error : `Line : 3 MATH ERROR | Line : 3 Invoice does not foot Reported`], 
                                [LINE:4, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:INV-Error_Test2, INVOICE_TOTAL:28,]],
                error : [[INV-Error_Test1:`File Error : The file is in an unsupported format`]]
```

I wrote the below method to achieve the above

```
def regex = "^Line\\s(?:(\\d+)\\s)?\\s*:\\s+(\\d+)?.+";
for (e in invLineItems ){
  def errors =  lipErrors.findAll{it.invoiceNumber==e.key} // finding the error messages with the invoice number
  errors.each{  // fetching the line numbre from error message and finding the matching record the invoice number and line number in invLineItems 
     int lineNumber
     if (it.errorMessage.matches(regex)) {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(it.errorMessage);
            if (m.find()) {
                 lineNumber = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
            }
          println "lineNumber = "+lineNumber
        }

    if(e.value['LINE_ITEM_NUMBER'].find{it==lineNumber.toString()}) {
      def data = lipErrors.findAll{it.invoiceNumber==e.key && it.errorMessage.matches("^Line\\s+"+lineNumber+"?\\:\\s+"+lineNumber+"?.+")}
      e.getValue().each{it.put("error", data.errorMessage.join("|"))}

     }   

  }
}
```

The code doesnt look like Groovy and using traditional java code mostly, am wondering whether the code can be simplified with Groovy approach

Comment: Just gonna toss this out there: most of the time when you've got a Map<X,List<Y>> what you really want is a Multimap. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one iteration is needed.

```
def invLineItems = [
    'INV-Error_Test1': [ 
        [LINE:1, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:'INV-Error_Test1', INVOICE_TOTAL:22], 
        [LINE:2, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:'INV-Error_Test1', INVOICE_TOTAL:24]
    ], 
    'INV-Error_Test2': [ 
        [LINE:3, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:'INV-Error_Test2', INVOICE_TOTAL:26], 
        [LINE:4, INVOICE_DATE:20150301, INVOICE_NUMBER:'INV-Error_Test2', INVOICE_TOTAL:28,]
    ]
]

invLineItems['INV-Error_Test2'].each { 
    println "LINE = "+ it['LINE']
}
```

`invLineItems['INV-Error_Test2']` gives the value of the second Map entry, iterating on which gets the nested map entry.

If you just need the values of `LINE` then

```
assert invLineItems.'INV-Error_Test2'*.'LINE' == [3, 4]
```

should be enough.

Comment: Can you check the updated question and suggest any changes please?

Comment: Is there a way to make a new hash map of <InvoiceNUmber, InvoiceTotal> without iterating over invLineItems

Comment: It is not clear to me what is being asked. Can this be posted as a new question, in order to get a feasible answer from a larger audience? @RanPaul

Comment: can you help me with this http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86159/regex-to-extract-selective-lines

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appreciate it. Can you also help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570648/java-8-find-and-replace-matching-strings

Comment: can u help me this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30789467/groovy-groupby-field-with-white-spaces